# How can I make the compile of Android Studio ignore normal problem?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2.

Code A can be compiled normally!

I'm testing these code, and I add the line `var name3 = ""` to the code, just like Code B.

When I compile Code B, the compiler of Android Studio refuse to compile and give the error information *Variable 'name3' is never used* !

I don't think that  *Variable 'name3' is never used  is a big error*, I'm only for test.

How can I make the compile of Android Studio ignore these normal problem and compile and run the Code B ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun HelloScreen() {
    var name1 by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    HelloContent(name2 = name1, onNameChange = { name1 = it })
}

@Composable
fun HelloContent(name2: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello, $name2",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = name2,
            onValueChange = onNameChange,
            label = { Text("MyLabel") }
        )
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun HelloScreen() {
    var name1 by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var name3 = ""
    HelloContent(name2 = name1, onNameChange = { name1 = it })
}

@Composable
fun HelloContent(name2: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
  ...//It's the same with the code above
}
```

**Added Content**

To Abhishek Dutt, thanks!

But the code can't be compile yet after I add `@SuppressWarnings` or `@Suppress("unused"),` you can see the error information below.

**Image A**

[image]

**My Answer:**

I think I have resolved the question.

I should to set `allWarningsAsErrors = true` as `false` in build.gradle. You can see Image B.

**Image B**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it didn't compile?  That's generally a warning, not an error.  You may have turned on the setting to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: How about `// var name3 = ""`? This instruction has no meaning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think here by this

> How can I make the compile of Android Studio ignore these normal problem and compile

you meant compiler warnings.
If so, then do the following:


 You can use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation, so that next time one compiles the code, the warnings won't be shown in the terminal.

To use it, just hover over the variable/method where it is showing the warning(in your case, it should be `name3`). Press `ALT` + `ENTER`(Windows or Linux) on the keyboard, click on the arrow, and you will see an option like this  `Suppress...` Use that one.

If this doesn't works, then you may have to manually add the annotation. You can also use the `@Suppress("unused")` annotation as well.

You may even look at the list of all the Suppress Warning [here](https://gist.github.com/elevenetc/bf795f94aaf3e92169ef)

Comment: Thanks! but the code can't be compile yet after I add `@SuppressWarnings` or `@Suppress("unused")`.

Comment: By going through the console, I think this issue is due to varying SDK versions, due to which they cannot be merged.  Make sure to have the same SDK versions in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle`

Comment: Thanks! I I think I have resolved the question, you can see my added content in the question.